# Linear programming: Converting nested absolute value

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

I am having trouble converting the following objective function into LP:
*$$ \min\left\lvert(\left\lvert x_1-a_1\right\rvert-\left\lvert x_2-a_2 \right\rvert )\right\rvert$$*
where $x$  is the decision variable and $(a)$ is 
an integer constant.

I tried adding the following constraints, but it did not work out:

$x_i-a_i\le y_i$

$a_i-x_i\le y_i$

$y_1-y_2\le U$

$y_2-y_1\le U$

Comment: Why it didn't work out?  The only step missing is $\min U$, since we have $y_i \ge 0$.

Comment: I think the inner absolute values need to be modeled with binary variables (that part is non-convex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this needs to be modeled as a MIP:

\begin{align}
 \min\> & z\\
      & -z \le y_1 - y_2 \le z\\
      & y_i \ge x_i - a_i\\
      & y_i \ge -(x_i - a_i)\\
      & y_i \le x_i - a_i + \delta_i M\\
      & y_i \le -(x_i - a_i) + (1-\delta_i) M\\
      & \delta_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

where $M$ is large enough constant.